# Time complexity of recursive memoized solution for burst bubbles problem

Tags: algorithm, recursion, time-complexity, memoization

I am trying to solve this problem: https://leetcode.com/problems/burst-balloons/

This is the recursive memoized solution I came up with:

```
def maxCoinsMemo(nums: List[int], memo) -> int:
            if len(nums) == 1:
                return nums[0]
            key = ''.join(str(num) for num in nums)
            if key in memo:
                return memo[key]
            maxCoinsRes = []
            for i in range(len(nums)):
                if i == 0:
                    res = 1*nums[i]*nums[i+1]
                elif i == len(nums)-1:
                    res = nums[i-1]*nums[i]*1
                else:
                    res = nums[i-1]*nums[i]*nums[i+1]
                nums_copy = nums.copy()
                nums_copy.pop(i)
                maxCoinsRes.append(res + maxCoinsMemo(nums_copy, memo))
            memo[key] = max(maxCoinsRes)
            return memo[key]
```

Can someone please help me understand the time complexity of this solution as I am getting TLE error. Here is my understanding:

- The number of nodes in the function call stack (tree) is Sum(nCi) i
  goes from 1 to n, which should sum to 2^n.
- I am doing a constant amount of computation per node.

Hence, the time complexity should be O(2^n). Am I correct?

Comment: `n` can be as large as 300, so O(2^n), exponential time, if so would not be correct

Comment: Yes, I do understand that, but also wanted to know if the time complexity O(2^n) is correct?

Comment: `for i in range(len(nums)):` ... `nums_copy = nums.copy()` is not constant work but as much as n². `for num in nums` means do something up to n times. I'm not familiar with the language

Comment: Thanks, yes you are right. I am doing some O(m) amount of computation where 1<m<n, so let's say it's O(n) per computation. But then the for loop is what I am having a hard time understanding. If I look at it from the work done per tree node approach, I am doing O(n) work for O(2^n) nodes, so shouldn't it be O((2^n)*n) or roughly O(2^n)?
Following your logic, what would be the final time complexity? This code is in Python BTW, sorry I missed that in my post.